# Automatically convert high res image or svg into multisized ico?

Tags: icon

Is there any software or script that will automatically convert a high res image or an svg into the multiple dimensions needed to create a proper multisized ico?

Ideally it would resize the file into the multiple files with the correct dimensions, then pack it into an ico, but something that will resize the file into multiple files would be good as well if the other thing doesnt exist.

Comment: There are lots of good apps out there that do the trick. I am currently using [Axalis Icon Workshop](http://www.axialis.com/download/). Maybe you can look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is a job for ImageMagik. In fact you can find this in the ImageMagik cookbook:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://realfavicongenerator.net/ . It's helped me out a number of times.

Comment: Favicon != icon

Comment: @ZachSaucier not exclusively, but ico are used for favicons.

Comment: This doesn't answer more than 5% of the question. Or maybe I'm wrong, maybe it answers 7% of the question. You're right, I'm being unpleasant, because this doesn't answer 95% of the question. Or maybe it doesn't answer 93% of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Iconslate is a good app http://www.kodlian.com/apps/icon-slate
otherwise try apple's Icon composer